# how to find the histogram of an input image using python?

Tags: python, histogram

i am trying to find the histogram of an input image. But instead of seeing a histogram, the code runs then stops without showing anything. Can someone point out to me why this is happening?

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('jack.jpg'))
# convert to grayscale
# do for individual channels R, G, B, A for nongrayscale images

img = np.uint8((0.2126* img[:,:,0]) + \
    np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) +\
         np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2]))


plt.histogram(img,10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing [`histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) with [`hist`](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist). And yes, `plt.histogram` is a call to `numpy.histogram`.

Try this:

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('jack.jpg'))
# convert to grayscale
# do for individual channels R, G, B, A for nongrayscale images

img = np.uint8(0.2126 * img[:,:,0]) +\
      np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) +\
      np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2])

plt.hist(img,10)
plt.show()
```

[edit to answer comment]

According to the documentation (links above on the functions names), `np.histogram` will `Compute the histogram of a set of data`, returning:

- hist : array The values of the histogram. [...]
- bin_edges : array of dtype
  float Return the bin edges (length(hist)+1).

And `plt.hist` will `Compute and draw the histogram of x`, returning a tuple `(n, bins, patches)`.

Comment: thank you for that. But i am confused. Aren't the two the same? Whats the difference?